# How do I fix my npm that seems to be infinitely looping?

Tags: node.js, npm

I was trying to change my **npm** and **npm-cache** folders to `d:\\npm-global` and `d:\\npm-cache`

I managed to do a `npm config set cache d:\npm-cache`

When I tried to do a `npm config set prefix d:\npm-global` I accidentally put a ' in the folder string as I was hitting enter. I deleted the errant folder after trying a `npm i -g gulp` and to my horror, npm stopped working altogether, it just sits there with my command prompt rocking up to 50% CPU usage.

Help please! I've tried searching the registry and other places, even **uninstalled and re-installed the nodejs msi package** on Windows. This reset the `D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc` file.

Still no luck. I can't get npm to work again. :(

**edit** A little digging in and I realized there is a second node server running via Adobe Creative Cloud. I doubt this is the problem though as when I run `npm` from the cmd.exe prompt, the correct (d:\program files\nodejs) version of the npm server is executed for that process.

**edit** so only *sometimes* when I hit Control-C, I'll get this error:

[image: npm error]

seems like it's trying to find a file that doesn't exist. However, I cleared out the `AppData\Roaming\npm` folder and the reinstalls reset the default `d:\program files\nodejs\....npm\npmrc` file. I also made sure that the environment variable `NODE_PATH` is not set. It wasn't set when it was working. I set it when I was trying to make my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to modify your config settings manually by modifying `~/.npmrc`

Comment: Already did that. after reinstalling, my `d:\program files\nodejs\...\npm\npmrc` file is reset to the default. No luck. :(

Comment: You're so right actually @jakemingolla I didn't realize there was a .npmrc file in `c:\users\userName` I thought the AppData npmrc file was the windows equivalent of `~/.npmrc` turns out, there are three npmrc files in Windows: home, program files and appdata.

Answer (score 0):

@jakemingolla was right so I marked that answer as accepted (thanks Jake), but I also asked this in the NPM forum and did a little test after I got it working. I thought this might help someone: https://npm.community/t/i-killed-my-npm-on-windows-trying-to-move-some-folders-reinstalling-nodejs-isnt-resetting-the-problem/5743/8?u=chi11ax